# How to disable dates before today in jquery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable dates before today but dont work with min and max.

```
view:

   <input id="date_modified" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
```

jquery:

```
        $('#date_modified').persianDatepicker({
            observer: true,
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
            min: [1396,2,10],
            max: [1396,2,20]


        }).pDatepicker('setDate', [today]);


    });
```

Comment: How do you like to give me a vote.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 $('#date_modified').persianDatepicker({
            observer: true,
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
            min: [1396,2,10],
            max: [1396,2,20],
            minDate: new Date()


        }).pDatepicker('setDate', [today]);


    });
```

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna min and max I blive are the dates Datepicker can show

Answer (score 0):

Use the **minDate** property in JQuery UI datepicker API. 
Use **minDate:0** in your jQuery function.
`$('#date_modified').persianDatepicker({
            observer: true,
            format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
            min: [1396,2,10],
            max: [1396,2,20]
            minDate:0
        }).pDatepicker('setDate', [today]);
    });`